# Difference between while not __ and while __ == false ? (python)

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to distinguish between different ways of writing while loops.

I am writing this specifically for a poker game where I distinguish between different hand types. When writing my `is_pair` function, I start by saying `pair = False`. The only way I have found that continues the loop is if I say `while pair == False: ...`. For my `is_flush` function I am able to set `flush = True` and the `while` loop runs on `while flush` which continues the loop until `flush` is not true any more.

I have tried `while not pair:` but that didn't work. I want it to continue while `pair` is `False` so when it has found a pair it will return as `True`.

I think the statement for `flush` just looks cleaner and I am wondering if there is another way to incorporate that style into my pair function.

Comment: There is little difference, other than bad style.

Comment: and if `while not pair:` did not work, then you have probably been assigning other values to it that are truthy but are not equal to `False`.

Comment: If `pair` is a boolean, and you want to continue while `pair` is `false` then `while not pair` should work. If it doesn't then you have another problem somewhere. You're going to need to show a code sample of what doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `while not pair:` loop did not work, you have found an important difference: `pair == False` only tests true if `pair` is set to `0` or `False` (the only two values that test as equal to `False`), while `while not pair` tests for [any truth value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) (inverting that value).

You appear to have assigned some *other* value to `pair` that is neither of those two values causing the behaviour to change (a truthy value to break out early, or a falsey value to keep the loop going longer than expected).

It is *that difference* that is one of the reasons why the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) recommends you always use `if true_expression` or `if not false_expression` rather than use `== True` or `== False`:

> - Don't compare boolean values to `True` or `False` using `==`.
>
>   Yes:   `if greeting:`
>     No:    `if greeting == True:`
>     Worse: `if greeting is True:`

Last but not least, for a `while ...:` loop that simply tests against a single boolean flag (`while flag:` or `while not pair:`), consider using `while True:` and `break` instead. So rather than do:

```
flag = True
while flag:
    # ...
    if condition:
        flag = False
```

do this instead:

```
while True:
    # ...
    if condition:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from actually having little or no difference at all,

Using **False** in a **==** comparison allows usage of 0 and 1.

```
0 == False
1 == True
```

Using **not** is inversion of current value.

```
not 0 == True
not 1 == False
not False == True
```

You can use in your program assuming that **pair** can only contain boolean values:

```
while not pair:
```

If you however still want to use a variable that can contain both boolean and number, you can use:

```
while pair is False:
```

Comment: *while any number above 0 == True.* No, only `1 == True`. Higher numbers do not compare true to either boolean value.